# Construct Pydantic models from json at Runtime

Tags: python, pydantic

From Pydantic [documentation](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/integrations/datamodel_code_generator/), it's described how to statically create a Pydantic model from a json description using a code generator called `datamodel-code-generator`.

My question here, is there a way or a workaround to do it dynamically in runtime without using a code generator. So I can construct Pydantic validators and use them when running the application. Something like:

```
validator_description = {
    "$id": "person.json",
    "title": "Person",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "first_name": {"type": "string", "description": "The person's first name."},
        "last_name": {"type": "string", "description": "The person's last name."},
        "age": {"description": "Age in years.", "type": "integer", "minimum": 0},
    },
}

Person = Pydantic.from_dict_description(validator_description)

data = {"first_name": "John", "last_name": "Doe", "age": 25}

Person(**data)  # accepted
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the datamodel-code-generator "official documentation" mentioned on the page you reference, datamodel-code-generator can be used as a module to get the dictionary to python-code-string (see https://koxudaxi.github.io/datamodel-code-generator/using_as_module/).

Here is there relevant example code (to avoid problems with their pages changing)

```
from datamodel_code_generator import DataModelType, PythonVersion
from datamodel_code_generator.model import get_data_model_types
from datamodel_code_generator.parser.jsonschema import JsonSchemaParser

json_schema: str = """{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "number": {"type": "number"},
        "street_name": {"type": "string"},
        "street_type": {"type": "string",
                        "enum": ["Street", "Avenue", "Boulevard"]
                        }
    }
}"""


data_model_types = get_data_model_types(
    DataModelType.PydanticV2BaseModel,
    target_python_version=PythonVersion.PY_311
)
parser = JsonSchemaParser(
   json_schema,
   data_model_type=data_model_types.data_model,
   data_model_root_type=data_model_types.root_model,
   data_model_field_type=data_model_types.field_model,
   data_type_manager_type=data_model_types.data_type_manager,
   dump_resolve_reference_action=data_model_types.dump_resolve_reference_action,
                       )
result = parser.parse()
```

Then, assuming that there isn't a way to send in a schema that would cause their parser to generate malicious code, you just need to run

```
exec(result)
```

EDIT: Here is a worked out example using the example code.  I get an error with your schema, which I have not tried to debug.

```
>>> from datamodel_code_generator import DataModelType, PythonVersion
>>> from datamodel_code_generator.model import get_data_model_types
>>> from datamodel_code_generator.parser.jsonschema import JsonSchemaParser
>>> json_schema: str = """{
...     "type": "object",
...     "properties": {
...         "number": {"type": "number"},
...         "street_name": {"type": "string"},
...         "street_type": {"type": "string",
...                         "enum": ["Street", "Avenue", "Boulevard"]
...                         }
...     }
... }"""
>>> parser = JsonSchemaParser(
...    json_schema,
...    data_model_type=data_model_types.data_model,
...    data_model_root_type=data_model_types.root_model,
...    data_model_field_type=data_model_types.field_model,
...    data_type_manager_type=data_model_types.data_type_manager,
...    dump_resolve_reference_action=data_model_types.dump_resolve_reference_action,
... )
>>> result = parser.parse()
>>> print(result)
from __future__ import annotations

from enum import Enum
from typing import Optional

from pydantic import BaseModel


class StreetType(Enum):
    Street = 'Street'
    Avenue = 'Avenue'
    Boulevard = 'Boulevard'


class Model(BaseModel):
    number: Optional[float] = None
    street_name: Optional[str] = None
    street_type: Optional[StreetType] = None

>>> exec(result)
>>> m = Model(**{'number': 1, 'street_name': 'Main', 'street_type': 'Street'})
>>> print(m)
number=1.0 street_name='Main' street_type=<StreetType.Street: 'Street'>
>>>
```

Comment: You would need to run `exec` because `eval` only works on expressions.

Comment: My bad.  I have made the correction @juanpa.arrivillaga pointed out.